# Write file to another UNIX server

Tags: java

Currently I am using weblogic for application server and it is running in one machine. I have to write the pdf(or any file type) to another Unix server. Can anyone please help me find the solution.

Comment: run `scp` command using java Process class : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_process.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and raw solution would be a SSH connection. There exists several Java libraries for SSH such as http://www.jcraft.com/jsch. Open a connection, write your file, close the connection. Of course you need the corresponding SSH keys and privileges to do this on the remote machine.

Comment: Hi Thomas Uhrig, I am sorry, i could not get you as i am not well aware of SSH connection.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to mount the remote directory to your local server via smb or NFS (keyword sharing). Then you don't have to put any code for the copy job into your application. Instead the operating system will take care for the operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, Currently Application Server is in Solaris box and another server is in UNIX...Will this solution work for the same..?

Comment: NFS works for all Unix (e.g. Solaris) and linux versions, smb even in combination with MS Windows,